# How to call processing toolbox in Qgis' python console

Tags: qgis, python, statistics

I have been trying to use processing toolbox via Python console in QGIS 2.0.1. I am able to write the following commands:

[image]

I am particularly interested to run 'r.statistics' from GRASS module.

[image]

My question is how to arrange the input parameters sequentially and what does each parameter mean? For example, in the above screenshot, when I type the help, I can see the parameter inputs,

```
processing.runalg('grass:r.statistics', base, cover, method, -c, GRASS region parameter, Grass region cell size, output)
```

I can understand that 'base = input raster', 'method = avg, mean, std' and 'output=outputfile to eb declared'.

But I am not sure what are 'cover=', '-c','GRASS region means'? How can I get further help on that? If I were to run the function 'r.statistics' via processing toolbox, how should the exact/correct command look like?

```
processing.runalg('grass:r.statistics', 'C:\mydata\dem.tif', cover, '1', -c, GRASS region parameter, Grass region cell size, 'C:\mydata\outputdem.tif')
```

Can anyone help me what to put in place of rest of the parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

To learn the processing module in Python, the easiest solution for me is:

1. execute the Processing command (from the Toolbox), for example v.to.rast.val
2. examine the "processing_qgis.log" file in the ".qgis2/processing/" folder

where you can examine all the running algorithms:

```
 ALGORITHM|Mon Oct 28 2013  
 12:30:34|processing.runalg("grass:v.to.rast.value","/Users/Shared/polygon.shp",0,1,"202563.92575,204206.182887,89106.9864984,89783.2100251",0,-1,0.0001,"/Users/Shared/polyraster.tif")
```

The actual commands are in:

- "grass_batch_job.sh" or "grass_batch_job.bat" files (in the ".qgis2/processing/" folder) for GRASS GIS;
- "saga_batch_job.sh" or "saga_batch_job.bat" files for SAGA GIS;
- "processing_script.r" file for R.

So, in the Python console:

```
import processing
processing.runalg("grass:v.to.rast.value","/Users/Shared/polygon.shp",0,1,"202563.92575,204206.182887,89106.9864984,89783.2100251",0,-1,0.0001,"/Users/Shared/polyraster.tif")
processing.runalg("grass:r.statistics","/Users/Shared/polyraster.tif","/Users/Shared/mydem.asc",1,True,"202086.577,205625.414407,88411.048,90534.3504441",0,"/Users/Shared/test.tif")
```

You can also use one of the displayed layers:

```
vectorlayer = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer().source()
processing.runalg("grass:v.to.rast.value",vectorlayer,0,1,"202563.92575,204206.182887,89106.9864984,89783.2100251",0,-1,0.0001,"/Users/Shared/polyraster.tif")
```

but before, you need to understand all the parameters of the command [r.statistics](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.statistics.html) and the problems as [r.statistics limitation to CELL](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/r-statistics-limitation-to-CELL-td4017639.html)

Comment: You can actually access the log from within QGIS. It's not necessary to dig out the file from some folder.

Comment: Perhaps, but these files are interesting if you really want to understand how processing (or sextante) works.

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for the reply. As suggested by gene, how would I execute the Processing command of 'v.to.rast.value'? Do I have to run the v.to.rast.value from GRASS gui via Qgis first to see log file? Then shall I check qgis/processing ?

Comment: gene, how did you generate the following log file? 

ALGORITHM|Mon Oct 28 2013  
 12:30:34|processing.runalg("grass:v.to.rast.value","/Users/Shared/polygon.shp",0,1,"202563.92575,204206.182887

Did you run v.to.rast.value from GRASS gui initially to see the log file in qgis2/processing folder?

Comment: I use the Toolbox command GRASS.../vector (v*)/v.to.rast.value (not from the GRASS plugin)

Comment: Big +1 for pointing me to the log file!