# Can not run grass:r.to.vect in Qgis console

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I call using `processing.alghelp("grass:r.to.vect")`

I looked input:

```
 <ParameterRaster>
feature <ParameterSelection>
-s <ParameterBoolean>
GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER <ParameterExtent>
GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER <ParameterSelection>
output <OutputVector>


feature(Feature type)
    0 - line
    1 - point
    2 - area
GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER(v.out.ogr output type)
    0 - auto
    1 - point
    2 - line
    3 - area
```

then I try to do , 
`processing.runalg("grass:r.to.vect" , iface.activeLayer,2, True, None,3,r"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\1\temp\drfsg\zhopa.shp")")`
but it returns an error, what I did wrong? the project is only one raster layer

Comment: You should use correct path-notation in strings: r"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\1\temp\drfsg" or "C:/Users/user2/Desktop/1/temp/drfsg" or "C:\\Users\\user2\\Desktop\\1\\temp\\drfsg"
Don't know if thats the issue..

Comment: that is not the way, it gives another error , 'int' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I think your GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER needs no int (your value is 2) but should be a string like it was used here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75666/how-to-call-processing-toolbox-in-qgis-python-console

Comment: processing.runalg("grass:r.to.vect" , iface.activeLayer,2, True, None,3,r"C:\Users\user2\Desktop\1\temp\drfsg\zhopa.shp")  writing does not issue error, but nothing happens, does not work

Comment: if the code runs without an error than it is likely a problem with the dataset used. Data values, data size, for example. So please give more information about what you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a raster, I want it to turn the console into a vector using, r.to.vect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent QGIS versions have implemented **GRASS7** into its *processing framework* as default so you may need to use `grass7:r.to.vect` instead of `grass:r.to.vect`. I have also experienced issues when trying to set the `GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER` to blank, instead I use the extents of the input layer as that's usually what I am interested in.

So you could try the following code into the python console:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo
import processing

# Identify raster layer
raster = iface.activeLayer()
fileName = raster.source()
fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileName)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileName, baseName)

# Define the extent of the region
extent = rlayer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

processing.runalg("grass7:r.to.vect",rlayer,2,True,"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),3,"C:/Users/user2/Desktop/1/temp/drfsg/zhopa.shp")
```

Comment: thank you very much it works on both the  version Qgis 12.8 and 12.2 as ))) Is it possible in this vector layer to make more transparent the fill?

Comment: @АзаматВалиев - Most welcome, glad it worked! You can make it transparent by changing its **style** properties by _right-clicking_ the layer and going to `Properties > Style` :)

Comment: and whether it is an important question, Grass gis 7 coverage of the region, select the coverage on the map instead of coordinates?

Comment: and about transparency, I'm doing a module, so that would not have to manually change namely through the console

Comment: @АзаматВалиев - You can define your own coordinates by replacing `"%f,%f,%f,%f"% (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)` with `"0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0"` (note they are inside a string). If you want to change the transparency of the layer, there are a number of posts asked here on GIS:SE such as this one: [How do I set layer transparency in QGIS 2.0 with Python?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77391/how-do-i-set-layer-transparency-in-qgis-2-0-with-python)

Comment: thank you very much, and the last question that worries me, is it possible process "save as" in the console? I need to save as well as in the horizontal and vertical resolution to put the 5 by 5 meters (pixel)

Comment: @АзаматВалиев - I'm guessing you asked [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227692/using-processing-in-console-qgissave-tiff-and-specify-the-pixel-size-5-x-5-how)? In which case, take a look at these posts which might help, you can specify the width and height: [Export raster layer in python to specific folder](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189590/export-raster-layer-in-python-to-specific-folder); and [QGis Save Raster as Rendered Image](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68803/qgis-save-raster-as-rendered-image)

Comment: Yes, I tried the codes thanks, but does not go out, you can please try to maintain some sort of screen with a resolution of 5 to 5 meter, pixels through the console